# Creating universal binary using XCode 4.0

Tags: desktop-application, xcode4, universal-binary

I have installed XCode 4.0 in my system recently. I need to create universal binary for one of my Desktop app. How do I do this in XCode 4.0?

Thanks and Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 4):

To build a binary for more than one "architecture" at the same time, select in the build settings which architectures shall be used for release builds and then make a release build, which means in Xcode 4, first create a second scheme that builds release (since your default scheme most likely builds debug), select this scheme and build it. Or was universal binary referring to a binary with Intel and PPC code? Well, in that case the answer is: Xcode4 does not support PPC any longer. Officially you have to use Xcode3 to create binaries that contain code for Intel and PPC architectures. Xcode4 only supports two Mac architectures: Intel 32 bit and Intel 64 bit; however a build configuration can be configured to build for both of these at the same time and put the code into a single binary, which would also be some kind of universal binary.

You can bring PPC support back to Xcode4 as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4), but you should really know what you are doing before you are applying hacks like that one.

Comment: Thanks for this. I came here via Google and the info at the link you provided seems to do the trick.