# XCode 4 and XCode 3.2.6 side-by-side

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4, osx-leopard

I need to build one iOS app and one Mac OS app on the same machine. Mac OS app needs to run on 10.5, and even though Apple claims you can build with the 10.6 SDK and run on 10.5 by setting the right target value, it's not true. Simple things, like the name/version of `libssl`, are different on 10.5 and 10.6 which makes this impossible.

Anyway, so I'm about to try and install XCode 3.2.6 on the same machine as I have XCode 4 on - any tips/gotchas/guides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should work fine, however it's best to install XCode4 last.  So if you install XCode3 you'll want to re-install XCode4 as well after (to keep the system tools at the latest version).

I'd also recommend XCode4 go into /Developer, and XCode3 goes into a folder with some other name, as it's had more time to be hammered out to work installed in different locations.

Comment: Thanks - so I have XCode 4 now. If I understand this correctly, I should install 3.2.6 to /XCode3 and then re-install XCode4? Or should I uninstall XCode 4 first?

Comment: I don't think you have to uninstall first, just install XCode3 then re-install XCode4.

Comment: So what I did was get the 10.5 SDK from XCode 3.2.6, drop it in next to the 10.6 SDK in XCode 4 and now I can use XCode 4 to build 10.5 and 10.6 apps.

Comment: Good thinking. I'll keep that in mind if I have to do the same.

Comment: This is very informative, and already described thoughtfully here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4