# Xcode 3 and Xcode 4: the correct way to install both with Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xamarin.ios, osx-snow-leopard, monodevelop

I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 with Xcode 3 already installed (in /Developer by default). Now I would like to install Xcode 4 without removing Xcode 3 (or reinstalling if necessary)?

Can I first uninstall Xcode 3 (with terminal command), then install Xcode 4 in /Developer dir and, finally, reinstall Xcode 3 in /Xcode3 dir?

Since I'm using also Monotouch and Monodevelop 2.8, I would like to use Xcode 4 as first.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds right (as long as you don't use OSX Lion, where installing XCode3 requires a few more steps). Look at the answer/comments for question [XCode 4 and XCode 3.2.6 side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481545/xcode-4-and-xcode-3-2-6-side-by-side)

Also the order is important since some shared UNIX utilities will be installed globally (outside the /Developer/ root) and you want to have the latest ones (or at least the same ones as everyone else ;-)

Comment: During the install you can choose not to install the UNIX utilities. This is useful when side-by-side installing an older SDK after a newer one.

Comment: @poupou Thank you. In your first reply, what do you mean with where _installing XCode3 requires a few more steps_? Do I have to put Xcode 3 installation in a different folder only?

Comment: In your second reply, instead, do I need to uncheck only UNIX utilities (as mhutch suggested)? I don't remember very well, but when you install XCode, the installation app provides 3 checkboxes: Developer System Tools, UNIX and System Tools. Do I need to unchecked only UNIX? or also System Tools?

Comment: @flex_addicted my first comment was about "OSX Lion" only (to generalize the answer) so it should not be a concern to you (and is not about the location). For the second I don't recall offhand for sure for System Tools (but UNIX for sure) - but the installer will warn tell you what's shared (that's how I learned this). Just read the text carefully and you should be ok :)

Answer (score 1):

From what i know you can install the new XCode and the old one get moved to /Developer.old and stil very much usable.