# Using Xcode 4 to create Universal binary

Tags: gcc, xcode4, llvm, universal-binary

I've used [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4) to restore PPC support to Xcode 4.

However, every time I tried to create a universal binary, it would just create an Intel binary. After a lot of experimentation with parameters, I think I found the solution.

I had to set the Architectures *and* the Valid Architectures settings to ppc i386 x86_64

It then seems I have to explicitly set the compiler version to GCC 4.2, rather than LLVM GCC 4.2 which it defaults to.

So my question is, are there any implications to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any implications by doing this:

- **Architectures** and **Valid Architectures** only control the binaries generated as well as the resulting fat binary. They are mainly **arch** flags.
- selecting GCC 4.2 instead of LLVM GCC 4.2 is not necessary in my opinion; there are only few cases where [the LLVM GCC 4.2 does not match the GCC 4.2 features](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-llvm-gcc/_index.html).