# XCode 4 - using GCC 4.0 to compile?

Tags: xcode, gcc, compiler-construction, xcode4

Code coverage for xcode 4 only works on GCC 4.0.
How can I set my compiler to use GCC 4.0 instead of GCC 4.2.
Do i need to download 4.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC 4.0 is not installed with Xcode 4. You can get it back by following the directions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4) about adding support for 10.4 and 10.5 SDKs to Xcode 4.