# xcode - Using Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 to compile for PowerPC CPUs

Tags: macos, gcc, xcode4, llvm, powerpc

I'm working on someone else's application and so far he has built it in XCode 4. XCode 4 has eliminated support for PowerPC architectures, but we would still like to support PowerPCs for some of our users.

I have followed [this tutorial on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4), informing me how to restore ppc compatibility to XCode 4, however, this is for the GCC (4.2) compiler which throws a lot of warnings and some errors when compiling the code. The code is optimized around Apple's LLVM 3.0.

My questions:

- Is it possible to use Apple LLVM
  compiler 3.0 for Power PC deployment?
- How would one go about doing this?
- What settings variables do I need to 
  set in order to get PPC compatibility
  when compiling?

Thank you!

Comment: LLVM itself apparently supports PowerPC; you might just have to compile it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much no, it's not possible. Apple LLVM 3.0 hasn't been tested or verified to work at all with PowerPC.