# How to make my Cocoa application targeting Intel based Mac and old PPC system?

Tags: cocoa

I am in the process of creating an application that run on Intel based mac. But subsequently, I also want to make it able to run in Power PC based system.

Can Xcode 4 accomplished this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from SO article : [How can we restore ppc/ppc64 as well as full 10.4/10.5 SDK support to Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4/5380923#5380923) 
And in the proces of creating a universal binary for both... I hope it's okay

Comment: It works... but unfortunately, I must change a lot of code in the existing application to be able to run it in Tiger (10.4).

Answer (score 1):

I believe PowerPC support (Rosetta) has been completely removed for Xcode 4. You can download an older version of Xcode here: http://connect.apple.com

Comment: Thnanks @NeilMonday, I already had xcode 3.x let me have a look on it.

Comment: Another thing to mention is that I think OS X 10.7 does not have rosetta support either. So you will be limited to 10.6 and earlier with Xcode 3.

Comment: Yes, I've read that Lion won't do PPC support. Luckily, I haven't upgrade to lion. Although there are some work that need to be Lion ready. Maybe I'll have to install both version