# How do I use gcc 4.5 in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, gcc, c++11

I have install g++-4.5, as I'm interested in the C++0x stuff (done by `sudo port install gcc45`). Now I've made sure it's my default compiler (using `gcc_select`) and all of my Makefile projects do just fine compiling with 4.5.

Now I'm starting a project in xCode 4. How do I get the same C++0x features from within xCode, a.k.a. tell xCode to use g++-4.5?

Comment: Try following step 4 in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4/5333500#5333500).

Comment: @ildjam Unfortunately, that seems to require a readymade plugin that I can move from one place to another. :(

Answer (score 1):

These two bloggers describe hacking together an Xcode plugin to use one's own build of clang.  I imagine you could use the same thing but substitute gcc 4.5's path.

http://belkadan.com/blog/2011/07/Using-Clang-from-SVN-in-Xcode/
http://shapeof.com/archives/2010/01/using_the_latest_llvm_with_xcode.html

I've been meaning to try, and found your question in my research.