# How to make a mac application support both 32bit and 64 bit systems

Tags: xcode, macos, universal-binary

I have created one mac application. It is showing 64bit as system requirement. but the app can run in 32bit systems also.
When I checked the Build Settings of the application. I found:

```
Valid Architecture   : i386 x86_64
```

and according to my knowledge these are intel based 32/64bit systems. But I want to make my application for all the processor and system 32 and 64bit.

How can I do so?? Should I delete them and resubmit the application?

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X has run on PowerPC (both 32-bit and 64-bit) and Intel (again, both 32-bit and 64-bit) processors. Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard was the last version of Mac OS X that ran on PowerPC machines. So, if your application targets 10.6 or higher, you can't support PowerPC Macs. For applications supporting 10.5 or lower, it is possible to build a Universal binary that will run on both Intel and PowerPC machines. Xcode 3.2.5 was the last version of Xcode to include support for compiling these Universal binary apps. So, if your really want to target PowerPC machines, you need to install Xcode 3.2.5. The setting you've already found is the correct one. In Xcode 3.2.5 and earlier, it will include the option to build for PowerPC.

(Note: It should be possible to set Xcode 4 up to build for PowerPC too, but installing Xcode 3.2.5 is the easier way to go.)

Comment: i have updated my xcode to 4 so I have lost the installation file for Xode 3.2.5.  Can you tell how to make Xcode4 build for powerpc too

Comment: I've never done it myself. This question seems to have a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4 . You will still need the Xcode 3.2.5 installer, but you should be able to download it from the Developer Downloads section of Apple's Developer website.