# how do I build a binary for an earlier version of MacOS using CMake?

Tags: macos, cmake

I am using CMake to compile and link some command-line tools that I have written (in C). My development machine is MacOS 10.15 Catalina.

I require the command-line tools to be able to run under MacOS High Sierra (10.13).

What changes do I need to make to my build environment to be able to achieve this?

At present, there is nothing in my CMakeLists that specifically targets Catalina, so I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong.

I have a Mojave machine and I know that these tools will run under Mojave.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165335/can-cmake-specify-the-base-sdk-on-mac-os-x) helps you further?

Comment: ok yes, that looks promising - thankyou.