# Where should I place the 10.4.u.sdk folder To make it recognized by xCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk

I have the sdk folder by its own, and I need to know where to put the sdk folder in order to have it recognized by the Latest xCode version (4.2) as 10.6 and 10.7...

Comment: [This Stack Overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4) will go a long ways in helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/

I gave up trying to get 10.5 to work with xcode 4.x (let alone 10.4). It just became too much of a hassle; so I don't know for sure how well this will for for you.