# Qt App Built on MAC 10.7.4 not working on 10.6

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

Hi I have created an Qt Appliation on Mac 10.7.4. and I got an .app file i.e ex myApp.app
When I try to run it on MAC 10.6 I am getting an error as showed in the below [image: Error Image]image

Comment: Click that 'Report...' button and show us where it crashed.

Answer (score 3):

First, try setting this in your application's *.pro file:

```
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6
```

This should hopefully enable weak linking for your build, which in theory would allow it to run on 10.6.

If that doesn't work, you have two other options. Build on 10.6. The binaries will run on 10.7 and 10.8. Or, manually try to install the 10.6 SDK as described here:

[Where to get macos SDK 10.6 for Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11989007/856199)

You will then have to configure your Qt project to target that SDK:

```
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6
QMAKE_MAC_SDK = /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

Comment: Thanks For ans 
Nikos Chantziaras, will try

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi Also make sure that your app bundle contains Qt libraries

Comment: That's not true; you can build against the 10.8 SDK and still target 10.6!  You just need to ensure you don't use (or provide alternatives to) any API that doesn't exist under 10.6 (including auto-layout in NIBs).

Comment: Thanks for comment trojanfoe, can you please tell me bit clearly

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi You don't need the 10.6 SDK at all and you can use the latest SDK supplied with the latest Xcode.  This is complicated however by the use of Qt, which will also need to be built to support 10.6 (and this is probably where the error lies).

Comment: @ trojanfoe: ok, But I have the issue in running the app on 10.6, Can you suggest me how can I fix it

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi You need to provide more information.  Press the "Report..." button so we can see where it crashed.

Comment: @SharanabasuAngadi I think trojanfoe might be right. What happens if you simply set `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6` in the *.pro file of your application?

Comment: @trojanfoe I updated my answer. You're right. Apple's docs say that weak linking is there exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @Nikos Chantziaras, ok will check that

Comment: @Nikos Chantziaras, Still no use Same issue