# Failed to update my existing app (armv6 supported) with the support for armv7s?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, arm

Start from XCode 4.5, we cannot build a single IPA which combine the support of `armv6`, `armv7` and `armv7s`, so how to provide update for my app to use iPhone5's feature?

Because from the doc:

**"You are permitted to expand your device requirements only. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your device requirements is not permitted."**

So we cannot drop support for the armv6 app, but it is impossible to launch a new app **as user already paid for the old app**, so how to update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is designed to stop people from downloading an app, only to find that the new version doesn't work -- a reasonable limitation.

But, when you build with Xcode 4.5 you'll find that the minimum version you can deploy on is iOS 4.3. As far as I know, no armv6 device can run 4.3. And you can't download apps that require higher versions of the OS than you're running.

In short: you *can* drop armv6 support. Users still running those old versions won't get further update/fixes but it won't suddenly stop working either.

Comment: It is okay for free app, but for ourself, it is a paid app, people expect to play our game in latest version of iOS instead of paying again..

Comment: Your comment suggests the opposite of what I said. I'm saying support the newest versions of the OS and drop support of the older ones. Dropping support of the older version won't remove it from older devices.

Comment: And yes, you can do this, even with paid apps. You can't support old OSes for ever.

Comment: My point is not supporting old OSes, I am saying supporting old customer who already bought our game, but they upgraded to new phone, the issue is according your suggestion they need to pay again for the game.

Comment: Er, no. I'm saying drop support for armv6 in your current game. There is no new game; there is no paying again.

Comment: hi, since my existing game already support armv6, when I don't provide a build that support armv6, it failed the validation during upload, saying "You are permitted to expand your device requirements only. Submitting an update to your binary to restrict your device requirements is not permitted"

Comment: My app has been in the store since August 2008 and is paid for. I have just validated (but not yet submitted) an update for iOS6 that includes support for iOS6 and drops support for the armv6 architecture. So there is something else going on here. Are you sure you've increased the deployment target to 4.3?

Answer (score 1):

Build armv6 version in older XCode and use `lipo` to merge them. With some fiddling you can probably add armv6 toolchain to the newer XCode as well. Some ideas from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4) (adding PPC to Xcode4) might be useful.

Comment: `lipo` can only merge static lib, can it be used to merge `IPA` file?

Comment: IPA is just a zip, it has the Mach-O executable inside.

Comment: Igor, you mean extract the IPA and only `lipo` the binary and put it back?