# Compile for OS X 10.6?

Tags: c++, macos, compilation

Normally for my OS X builds I have been compiling my applications on an old Mac Book Pro that runs 10.6.  This assures that I support this version of OS X.

However for various reasons, the MBP is no longer a long term option so I have been compiling on a more recent device which runs 10.8.  However when I do this, my application does not work on 10.6 even with the -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 flag set.  The error that happens when I set the flag is "Symbol not found: _wcsdup" in libSystem.B.dynlib

I looked up this error and the only recommendations I can find is to directly link against the 10.6 SDK.  However when  I tried copying the 10.6 SDK from my MPB to the new machine (because 10.6 SDK is not installed on 10.8), it fails to compile with errors like "error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory"  I assume this is because of the way I  "installed" the SDK, although others have had success with this.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you happen to be compiling with `-std=c++11`?  If so this won't work under 10.6 as it does not contain the library file; you need to use `-std=gnu++11` to work on 10.6 to 10.8.

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I am, that's interesting,  I will have to attempt a compile with that flag instead and see if it is successful.

Comment: You might need to make some changes to the code if you've used any C++11.  Some of it can be replaced with `tr1::` classes, however, but certainly not all.

Comment: @trojanfoe Unfortunately, double checking reveals that this is one of my apps that I have not compiled with C++11 support, so this is not the cause of my troubles with this particular app.

Answer (score 0):

Run 10.6 in a VM, like VMWare or VirtualBox.

Comment: This requires having the installation disc or dmg for 10.6 or a recovery partition where one might be stored, I have neither.

Comment: In addition you cannot (legally) run OS X in a virtual machine unless its the server version, which makes obtaining a legal copy even more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reinstall older SDKs and compilers with this procedure: [How can we restore ppc/ppc64 as well as full 10.4/10.5 SDK support to Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333490/how-can-we-restore-ppc-ppc64-as-well-as-full-10-4-10-5-sdk-support-to-xcode-4/11003002#11003002)

You need to change the path of xcode installs in the script.

Also you probably won't be able to use -std=c++11 when targeting 10.6 since you will mostly also need -stdlib=libc++ which is only available when targeting 10.7 or above.

Apple only distributes libc++ binaries since 10.7. You could build your own libc++ and deploy it with your app to 10.6 machines. But Apple hard coded the compiler to disallow -stdlib=libc++ when targeting anything lower than 10.7.